# Can't access WAMP site from the web with IP

Tags: wamp, wampserver

I'm running the latest version of wampserver with apache 2.4.2 and php 5.4.3. on Windows 2008.

I'm running two ip's, one for iis and one for apache. I did that by adding

Listen 123.456.78.999:80 
Listen 80

in httpd.conf. I also switched 'require local' to 'require all granted' in the  of both

'ServerName localhost:80' and 'DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/"'.

When entering the ip in the local browser, I get access. But when I enter it from the web/external browser, the browser cant find the server and just times out. Port 80 is forwarded, as I can access my IIS sites.

Is there anything else I should be doing to put my wamp online?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

Annnd the culprit was....Windows firewall. I thought that wouldn't be the case because apache and iis were both using the same port (80), but it turns out that there is an iis-only rule allowing traffic coming in on port 80! So I added a new inbound rule opening port 80, and voila, now everything works!