# Wampserver 3.0.6 cannot be reached by outside devices

Tags: windows-8, wampserver

After installing wampserver 3.0.6 on windows 8, it would seem that I cannot reach it from another pc or phone (they're connected with the same network). The message displayed in the navigator when trying to reach the server from another device (reach by typing the ipv4 adress in the navigator) is :

**This site can’t be reached**

**192.168.x.x took too long to respond.**

not the *Forbidden : access denied* window !

Comment: Where is the site located in the folder structure? Do you have a Virtual Host defined for the site?

Comment: This may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36810669/why-wamp-server-put-online-offline-option-is-missing/36825283#36825283

Comment: Also suggest update to WAMPSever 3.0.8. The upgrade will not effect you site(s) or the versions of Apache/MySQL/PHP that you have installed or are using

Comment: I already did all of the mentioned in the post you sent, yet it doesn't seem like the usual *wamp accebility issue* , I tried several things, but, still I can't find the problem. Could it be that **Windows 8** is causing this problem ?

Comment: I have the same problem, have you found the solution?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by allowing port **80** or any port that you use in firewall.

1. Open Windows Firewall
2. New Inbound Rules
3. Choose **Port** option, click next
4. Choose **TCP**, Specific local ports: **80**
5. Finished.

Link: [Can't access WAMP site from the web with IP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14013420/cant-access-wamp-site-from-the-web-with-ip)